# bootstrap navbar links not clickable once uncollapsed Rails

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

http://boiling-garden-2168.herokuapp.com open the link, when the window is small enough so the navbar collapses, and you click the icon-bar to uncollapse it, only my drop down and feedback link are able to be clicked. My login and register links are not able to be clicked on. Any idea why? I've been messing with this stupid bootstrap for days now. I finally got the collapse to work, but they are not clickable now. Also, I need the turbo links..

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
</div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="div-navbar-thing">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <% if logged_in? && current_user.status == 'career/education' %>
      <% if current_user.username == 'Curry' %>
        <li><%= link_to 'Add skill', new_skill_path(@skill), class: 'navbar-brand' %></li>
      <% end %>
      <li><%= link_to 'References', references_path, class: 'navbar-brand' %></li>
      <li><%= link_to 'My Degree', courses_path, class: 'navbar-brand' %></li>
      <li><%= link_to 'logout',  logout_path,    class: 'navbar-brand' %></li>
      <li><%= link_to 'Search Jobs',  jobs_path,    class: 'navbar-brand' %></li>




      <li><%= link_to '#', class: 'navbar-brand dropdown-toggle', 'data-toggle' => 'dropdown', "data-no-turbolink" => true do %>
        <%= current_user.username %> <span class='caret'></span>
      <% end %>
        <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
          <li> <%= link_to "My Profile", user_skill_path(current_user) %> </li>
          <li> <%= link_to 'Edit My Profile', edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
          <li> <%= link_to 'My Library', user_skills_path(:id => current_user.id) %></li>
          <li> <%= link_to 'My Docs/resumes',     resumes_path %></li>
        </ul>

      <li><div class="btn-group nav_item">
      <%= link_to '#', class: 'navbar-brand', 'data-toggle' => 'dropdown' do %>
      Earn Skills <span class='caret'></span>
    <% end %>         
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <% Category.all.each do |category| %>
          <li>
            <%= link_to category.name, category_path(category) %>
          </li>
          <% end %>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><%= link_to 'All Categories', skills_path %></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <% elsif logged_in? && current_user.status == 'Employer' %>

      <li><%= link_to 'logout',  logout_path,    class: 'navbar-brand' %></li>
      <li><%= link_to 'Post Job',  new_job_path,    class: 'navbar-brand' %></li>
      <li><%= link_to 'view/edit Jobs', job_path(:id => current_user.id), class: 'navbar-brand' %></li>
      <li><%= link_to 'Search Users',  jobs_path,    class: 'navbar-brand' %></li>
      <li><%#= link_to 'Our Jobs',     job_path, %></li>
      <li><div class="btn-group nav_item">
      <%= link_to '#', class: 'navbar-brand', 'data-toggle' => 'dropdown' do %>
      View Skills <span class='caret'></span>
    <% end %>         
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <% Category.all.each do |category| %>
          <li>
            <%= link_to category.name, category_path(category) %>
          </li>
          <% end %>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><%= link_to 'All Categories', skills_path %></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <% else %>
      <li><%= link_to 'log in',   login_path,    class: 'navbar-brand' %></li>
      <li><%= link_to 'Register', new_user_path, class: 'navbar-brand' %></li>
      <li><div class="btn-group nav_item">
      <%= link_to '#', class: 'navbar-brand', 'data-toggle' => 'dropdown' do %>
      Earn Skills <span class='caret'></span>
    <% end %>         
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <% Category.all.each do |category| %>
          <li>
            <%= link_to category.name, category_path(category) %>
          </li>
          <% end %>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><%= link_to 'All Categories', skills_path %></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <% end %>
    <li class='navbar-brand'><font color="red"><strong>Beta</strong></font></li>
    <li><%= link_to 'Give us Feedback', 'http://www.facebook.com/jetpackedu', :target => '_blank' %></li>


  </ul>

</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.nav>li` element has `position: relative` which is overlapping your links when collapsed.

Comment: That sounds really promising. I'm assuming that is a default setting since I that isn't anywhere in the file? What would the recommended position type be? should it be float?

Comment: @user3138341 Add the class `clearfix` to your `<li>`

Comment: You sir, are awesome. How did you even know that?